# Using the open source machine learning Datumbox framework

Tags: android, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes, datumbox

I am working in an intelligent android news application,  the app should extract news topics that contain specific keywords from the published news on the web , and then classify them to categories, I haven't any idea how to implement Naive Bayes classifier in the app, and so I think about implementing the open source machine learning Datumbox framework, any body knows about this framework "Datumbox" or used it before? especially on java or android?
Also if any body knows another way to implement a Nave Bayes classifier, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link for the example in Java right from Datumbox, I used this and it was good.

https://github.com/datumbox/NaiveBayesClassifier/blob/master/src/com/datumbox/opensource/examples/NaiveBayesExample.java